# Fragment declared in XML not accessible in class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've declared a fragment in my XML layout as;

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.android.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    android:tag="MyTag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now I need to access that fragment in class. I've tried following two methods but both are getting null.

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyTag");
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
```

Comment: you can find the fragment in fragment manager only after you add it to the fragmentmanager. Just by declaring in xml it won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

As Manish says you have to add it before you can use it.

```
phf = new PlaceholderFragment();

if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, phf).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `<fragment ... />` in another `Fragment`'s layout hence `getFragmentManager()` was not working. The answer was to make use of `getChildFragmentManager()`.